# Email validation only if field is non empty

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext, email-validation

This code works for username and mobile no according to my choice but it does not work for email  validation. **Note I want to check email only it is nonempty.How to check validation for email only this field is nonempty.**Remember I know the logics But how to put the logics in this code because** ** I have tried several logics but in email edit text does nothing.

```
public class Login extends BaseActivity {

    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;

    private ProgressDialog dialog;



    ArrayList<String> arealist;
    //ArrayList<GetterSetter> area;



    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_register);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_enter_name);
                EditText mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_mobNo);
                EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_email);




                // Check The Validity of empty fields
                boolean Resp = validate(new EditText[]{user,mobile});


                // Check The Validity of emailID
                    boolean e_valid = isEmailValid(email.getText());

                // Check The Validity of Mobile Numbers
                boolean mobile_valid = isMobValid(mobile.getText());

                if (Resp && mobile_valid && e_valid) {

                    PostJson();
                } else {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Field incorrect..!!!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if (Resp) {
                    String pass = mobile.getText().toString();
                    String e_check = email.getText().toString();
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pass) || pass.length() < 10) {
                        mobile.setError("Mobile number should be of 10 digits");}

                        else if (e_check!=null || e_check.length() >=1) {

                            email.setError("Email Address in invalid format");

                        Toast.makeText(Login.this,
                                "Email Address in invalid format",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // Chk Validation of mobile number

                            if (mobile_valid) {

                                if (e_valid) {


                                    if (isInternetPresent) {
                                        // setting progress bar to zero
                                        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
                                        dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
                                        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                                        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                                        dialog.setProgressNumberFormat(null);
                                        dialog.setProgress(0);
                                        dialog.show();

//                          Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Connecting....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
//                                  .show();

                                    } else {

                                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Unable to connect the server, please check your data settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                .show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }





            // =====To check the validation of Emails and Empty
            // Fields==========//

            public boolean isEmailValid(Editable email) {
                boolean isValid = false;

                String expression = "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
                        + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                        + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
                        + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                        + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
                        + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";
                CharSequence inputStr = email;

                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression,
                        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);

                if (matcher.matches()) {
                    isValid = true;
                }

                return isValid;
            }

            public boolean isMobValid(Editable mobile) {

                boolean isOk = false;

                String exp = "^[0-9]{10}$";
                CharSequence inputStr = mobile;

                Pattern pattern = Pattern
                        .compile(exp, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
                if (matcher.matches()) {
                    isOk = true;
                }
                return isOk;
            }

            public boolean validate(EditText[] fields) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                    EditText currentField = fields[i];
                    if (currentField.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {

                        currentField.setError("This field can't be empty");
//                      Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Enter all the fields..!!!",
//                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    // ==========//




    // =========================== Json Object==================//

    public void PostJson() {


            }



            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {


                Log.e("ERROR_LOG", "onFailure request" + e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error in Connection.....",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // //////// { onFinish body}///////////////////////////////
                super.onFinish();


                // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: check my edited answer..

Answer (score 2):

for validating email id use Android's default Email mathcher.

```
android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(your data).matches();
```

For Example.

```
if (etMail.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please enter your e-mail id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
} else if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(
                etMail.getText().toString().trim()).matches()) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please enter valid e-mail id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
}else{
    // Do your stuff
}
```

## EDIT :

```
if (user.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please enter username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
} else if (mobile.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please enter your mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
} else if (mobile.getText().length() < 10) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please enter valid mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
} else if (!etMail.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
    if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(
                etMail.getText().toString().trim()).matches()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please enter valid e-mail id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
    }
}else{
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Happy Coding..

Comment: how to put in above code bacause I tried this logic but not works in my code

Comment: your code is bit complicated you are checking same validation multiple time.. post your json in else part in my code.

Comment: How exactly you want your validations wants to be?

Comment: there are three fields a)name,b)mobileNo,c)email

Comment: name and mobile no should not be empty and mobile no must be 10 digits and email validation check only if it is non empty.

Comment: what happens if name and mobile number is non-empty and email is empty? will it allow to go further or will fire validation?

Comment: after name non empty it check emptyness of mobile then if mobile is non empty it check 10 digits of mobile no

Comment: after that it goes to email and check if it is empty then allow to go to next activity and if it is non empty it check the valid format of email

Answer (score 2):

I have edited your class.Hope it works now.

```
        public class  Login extends BaseActivity {

            JSONObject jsonobject;
            JSONArray jsonarray;

            private ProgressDialog dialog;



            ArrayList<String> arealist;
            //ArrayList<GetterSetter> area;



            public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
                Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_register);

                login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_enter_name);
                        EditText mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_mobNo);
                        EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_email);

                        if (user.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Please enter username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        } else if (mobile.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Please enter your mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        } else if (mobile.getText().length() < 10) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Please enter valid mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        } else if (!email.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                            if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(
                                    email.getText().toString().trim()).matches()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Please enter valid e-mail id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        }else{
                            // Do your stuff
                            PostJson();

                            if (isInternetPresent) {
                                // setting progress bar to zero
                                dialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
                                dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
                                dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                                dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                                dialog.setProgressNumberFormat(null);
                                dialog.setProgress(0);
                                dialog.show();

        //                          Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Connecting....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        //                                  .show();

                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Unable to connect the server, please check your data settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        }




                    }





                    // =====To check the validation of Emails and Empty
                    // Fields==========//

                    public boolean isEmailValid(Editable email) {
                        boolean isValid = false;

                        String expression = "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
                                + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                                + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
                                + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                                + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
                                + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";
                        CharSequence inputStr = email;

                        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression,
                                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);

                        if (matcher.matches()) {
                            isValid = true;
                        }

                        return isValid;
                    }

                    public boolean isMobValid(Editable mobile) {

                        boolean isOk = false;

                        String exp = "^[0-9]{10}$";
                        CharSequence inputStr = mobile;

                        Pattern pattern = Pattern
                                .compile(exp, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
                        if (matcher.matches()) {
                            isOk = true;
                        }
                        return isOk;
                    }

                    public boolean validate(EditText[] fields) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                            EditText currentField = fields[i];
                            if (currentField.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {

                                currentField.setError("This field can't be empty");
        //                      Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Enter all the fields..!!!",
        //                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }

            // ==========//




            // =========================== Json Object==================//

            public void PostJson() {


            }



            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {


                Log.e("ERROR_LOG", "onFailure request" + e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error in Connection.....",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // //////// { onFinish body}///////////////////////////////
                super.onFinish();


                // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            }
        });
                }


                }
```

Comment: how to put in above code bacause I tried this logic but not works in my code

Comment: Here is some issue after entering complete valid email address ,the post json not works

Comment: There is nothing that can stop the call of postjson method..i am sure that there will be a error in that method.please check

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this :

```
if (email.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
    // email is empty
} else {
    //email is not empty
}
```

Comment: how to put in above code bacause I tried this logic but not works in my code.